# What is the Rails way of rendering partials with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a character create form, that has two select inputs `clan` and `family` which are based depend on the `clan` so Dragon clan has different families then Lion clan.

My goal it to rerender just the _character_form partial.
I made a coffeescript function, that renders new.js.erb when the clan select is change, and in the new.js.erb form I render just the _form partial:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#character_clan', ->
  character_clan = $(this).val()
  character_name = $('#character_name').val()
  character_desc = $('#character_desc').val()
  $.get(window.location, { name: character_name, clan: character_clan, desc: character_desc  }) ->
```

It works well, but when the form faileds, the function stops working, because it is in the create action, and I don`t have route for the create action.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to load juts a partial from the javascript ? Or do I have to make, character#create route, or there is different way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to load juts a partial from the javascript ? Or do **I have to make, `character#create` route**, or there is different way to do this ?

The answer is more structural than it is specific -

You firstly need to appreciate that `Javascript` != `Rails`.

- **JS** - *Client Side*
- **Rails** - *Server Side*

Whilst there are some occasions where you can use Ruby `ERB` code in your JS, in 99% of circumstances, you should not put any Rails-dependent code into your asset pipeline.

This is the crux of your issue - you're trying to call a "partial" which has to be dynamically created. The *only* way this can happen is if you pass the data to your server through javascript ([`Ajax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) etc):

```
#app/views/characters/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @character, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :clan_id, Clan.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :description %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/characters_controller.rb
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @character = Character.new
   end

   def create
      @character = Character.new character_params
      @character.save
   end

   private

   def character_params
      params.require(:character).permit(:name, :clan_id, :description)
   end
end
```

-

> Is there a way to load juts a partial from the javascript

Yes, but it would not be a *partial* (unless you wanted it to be) -- it would be advisable to state the specific functionality you require.

The magic here will come in the form of [`layout`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout).

You mention you want to render a "partial" - what you're really asking is... *how can I render **just** the view from my controller?*. The answer is to set the layout depending on whether the request was `html` or [`xhr`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/xhr%3F):

```
#app/controllers/characters_controller.rb
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
   layout Proc.new { |c| c.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end
```

This will give you the ability to create the respective `character` record.

--

I was going to write about the need for [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) etc - if you'd like me to update the answer, I'll certainly do that.

Comment: I won`t have time to look to it today unfortunetly, but I will look at it tomorrow morning for certain. Thnx in advance for such complex answer :)

Comment: I have switched to the `remote: true`, I created create.js.erb file which redirects to wanted file.  And it works fine thnx

Answer (score -1):

something like following in a js.erb file

```
<%= raw escape_javascript(render('partial_name', :variable => @variable))%>
```

Comment: This will probably work, but I don`t have a create.js.erb file, I want to know is there a way to avoid creating a file just for this purpose.